# Android displays a grey map in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Android application containing a map which works fine when tested on devices with version 4 or 4.4, but when it is loaded on a device with Lollipop it shows a grey map. No errors are reported in the logcat and the problem is not related with the API key, since if I change it I obtain an output error. The google play services library has installed and updated in all devices.

The content of logcat is:

```
11-06 09:23:40.880    3895-3895/it.univr.veronapp I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 8301270
11-06 09:23:40.908    3895-4250/it.univr.veronapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x98045be0, tid 4250
11-06 09:23:44.932    3895-3949/it.univr.veronapp D/Volley﹕ [316] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?s=maps_android_api&v=3&action=map_start_up&it=map_load.712,on_create.1,on_resume.1,init.5&irt=712,6,8,5 0x4d844933 NORMAL 10> [lifetime=3339], [size=0], [rc=204], [retryCount=0]
11-06 09:23:44.933    3895-3895/it.univr.veronapp D/Volley﹕ [1] p.b: 3340 ms: [ ] https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?s=maps_android_api&v=3&action=map_start_up&it=map_load.712,on_create.1,on_resume.1,init.5&irt=712,6,8,5 0x4d844933 NORMAL 10
11-06 09:23:49.854    3895-3952/it.univr.veronapp D/Volley﹕ [319] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 11> [lifetime=6931], [size=135887], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
11-06 09:23:49.855    3895-3895/it.univr.veronapp D/Volley﹕ [1] p.b: 6931 ms: [ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 11
```